# Adding metadata/keywords to pdf

Tags: macos, pdf, metadata

What software, either Apple built-in or open-source, could add metadata/keywords to a pdf document?

I have tried Inkscape, but that overwrites metadata.

I want to add keywords specifically to an existing pdf, with no other changes.

I am investigate pdftk at least as command line tool. BigSur would be a plus, but not needed at this time.

Answer (score 1):

You can add keywords in Preview.
 <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>i</kbd>  for the inspector.

[image]

It doesn't seem to be able to add more complex metadata though.

Comment: I see the panel shown above. After adding keywords, the pdf document states "edited". However, upon saving, the keywords are lost. How have you been able to save the keywords with the pdf?

Comment: hmm, that's weird. I hadn't tested it, just knew I'd seen it there before. Nope, I can't get it to save either. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

[PDF Expert](https://pdfexpert.com/), from Readdle, can.

[image]